# parallel tests on Mac OS X Catalina crash with Postgres

Tags: django, postgresql, macos

After upgrading to Mac OS X Catalina my parallel django tests cash.

With this in settings I get a crash, without them (when sqlite is used everything is fine)

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'xx',
        'USER': 'xx',
        'PASSWORD': 'xx',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

Execution command is:
python manage.py test --settings=app.settings.test --parallel

The crash report contains this:

```
Process:               Python [30650]
Path:                  /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Identifier:            Python
Version:               3.7.5 (3.7.5)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        Python [30634]
Responsible:           Terminal [1592]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2019-12-15 10:04:41.315 -0800
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.15.2 (19C57)
Report Version:        12
Bridge OS Version:     4.2 (17P2551)
Anonymous UUID:        9B583AD7-1D7E-AA15-3286-DADFF9B92A49

Sleep/Wake UUID:       41900DFA-568F-4B5B-BFA4-0C5FF8D8C05F

Time Awake Since Boot: 54000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       2000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x000000011554baba
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process:   exc handler [30650]

VM Regions Near 0x11554baba:
    VM_ALLOCATE            000000011550b000-000000011554b000 [  256K] rw-/rwx SM=COW  
--> 
    shared memory          000000011558b000-000000011558f000 [   16K] r--/r-- SM=SHM  

Application Specific Information:
*** multi-threaded process forked ***
crashed on child side of fork pre-exec

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_trace.dylib           0x00007fff6ee9fc45 _os_log_preferences_refresh + 75
1   libsystem_trace.dylib           0x00007fff6eea0624 os_log_type_enabled + 618
2   com.apple.security              0x00007fff43daa6ad Security::DLDbListCFPref::loadPropertyList(bool) + 341
3   com.apple.security              0x00007fff43fee5f4 Security::KeychainCore::StorageManager::getSearchList(std::__1::vector<Security::KeychainCore::Keychain, std::__1::allocator<Security::KeychainCore::Keychain> >&) + 142
4   com.apple.security              0x00007fff43ff0704 Security::KeychainCore::StorageManager::optionalSearchList(void const*, std::__1::vector<Security::KeychainCore::Keychain, std::__1::allocator<Security::KeychainCore::Keychain> >&) + 114
5   com.apple.security              0x00007fff43fb3ea5 SecIdentitySearchCreate + 139
6   com.apple.security              0x00007fff43fc1548 _CreateSecItemParamsFromDictionary(__CFDictionary const*, int*) + 4109
7   com.apple.security              0x00007fff43fbf73b SecItemCopyMatching_osx(__CFDictionary const*, void const**) + 104
8   com.apple.security              0x00007fff43fc3024 SecItemCopyMatching + 338
9   com.apple.Heimdal               0x00007fff5976f303 keychain_query + 531
10  com.apple.Heimdal               0x00007fff5976cf4c hx509_certs_find + 92
11  com.apple.Heimdal               0x00007fff5972bb52 _krb5_pk_find_cert + 466
12  com.apple.GSS                   0x00007fff3a2539bb _gsspku2u_acquire_cred + 619
13  com.apple.GSS                   0x00007fff3a238c1c gss_acquire_cred + 940
14  libpq.5.dylib                   0x00000001054526e3 pg_GSS_have_cred_cache + 54
15  libpq.5.dylib                   0x0000000105440eb0 PQconnectPoll + 6356
16  libpq.5.dylib                   0x000000010543e026 connectDBComplete + 231
17  libpq.5.dylib                   0x000000010543e1ad PQconnectdb + 36
18  _psycopg.cpython-37m-darwin.so  0x00000001053fe587 conn_connect + 135
19  _psycopg.cpython-37m-darwin.so  0x00000001053ffbc0 connection_init + 336
20  org.python.python               0x00000001033dc7ee type_call + 172
21  org.python.python               0x00000001033a1453 _PyObject_FastCallDict + 264
22  org.python.python               0x00000001033a292f _PyObject_CallFunctionVa + 207
23  org.python.python               0x00000001033a2a90 _PyObject_CallFunction_SizeT + 129
24  _psycopg.cpython-37m-darwin.so  0x00000001053f98e0 psyco_connect + 192
25  org.python.python               0x00000001033a1cda PyCFunction_Call + 208
26  org.python.python               0x000000010342f70e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 7738
27  org.python.python               0x0000000103436bc9 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1698
28  org.python.python               0x00000001033a1678 _PyFunction_FastCallDict + 444
29  org.python.python               0x000000010342f627 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 7507
30  org.python.python               0x00000001033a1e0c function_code_fastcall + 106
31  org.python.python               0x00000001034363d5 call_function + 737
32  org.python.python               0x000000010342f32a _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 6742
33  org.python.python               0x00000001033a1e0c function_code_fastcall + 106
34  org.python.python               0x00000001034363d5 call_function + 737
35  org.python.python               0x000000010342f32a _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 6742
36  org.python.python               0x00000001033a1e0c function_code_fastcall + 106
37  org.python.python               0x00000001034363d5 call_function + 737
38  org.python.python               0x000000010342f32a _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 6742
39  org.python.python               0x00000001033a1e0c function_code_fastcall + 106
40  org.python.python               0x00000001034363d5 call_function + 737
41  org.python.python               0x000000010342f32a _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 6742
42  org.python.python               0x00000001033a1e0c function_code_fastcall + 106
43  org.python.python               0x00000001034363d5 call_function + 737
44  org.python.python               0x000000010342f32a _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 6742
45  org.python.python               0x00000001033a1e0c function_code_fastcall + 106
46  org.python.python               0x00000001034363d5 call_function + 737
47  org.python.python               0x000000010342f343 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 6767
48  org.python.python               0x0000000103436bc9 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1698
49  org.python.python               0x00000001033a1a00 _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords + 212
50  org.python.python               0x00000001034363d5 call_function + 737
51  org.python.python               0x000000010342f3de _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 6922
52  org.python.python               0x00000001033a1e0c function_code_fastcall + 106
53  org.python.python               0x00000001034363d5 call_function + 737
54  org.python.python               0x000000010342f32a _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 6742
55  org.python.python               0x0000000103436bc9 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1698
56  org.python.python               0x00000001033a1678 _PyFunction_FastCallDict + 444
57  org.python.python               0x00000001033a277f _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 131
58  org.python.python               0x00000001033a1b45 PyObject_Call + 136
59  org.python.python               0x000000010342f627 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 7507
60  org.python.python               0x0000000103436bc9 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1698
61  org.python.python               0x00000001033a1678 _PyFunction_FastCallDict + 444
62  org.python.python               0x00000001033a277f _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 131
63  org.python.python               0x00000001033df0ce slot_tp_call + 71
64  org.python.python               0x00000001033a18ae _PyObject_FastCallKeywords + 358
65  org.python.python               0x00000001034363ce call_function + 730
66  org.python.python               0x000000010342f3de _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 6922
67  org.python.python               0x00000001033a1e0c function_code_fastcall + 106
68  org.python.python               0x00000001034363d5 call_function + 737
69  org.python.python               0x000000010342f32a _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 6742
70  org.python.python               0x00000001033a1e0c function_code_fastcall + 106
71  org.python.python               0x000000010342f627 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 7507
72  org.python.python               0x0000000103436bc9 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1698
73  org.python.python               0x00000001033a1678 _PyFunction_FastCallDict + 444
74  org.python.python               0x000000010342f627 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 7507
75  org.python.python               0x00000001033a1e0c function_code_fastcall + 106
76  org.python.python               0x00000001034363d5 call_function + 737
77  org.python.python               0x000000010342f32a _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 6742
78  org.python.python               0x00000001033a1e0c function_code_fastcall + 106
79  org.python.python               0x00000001034363d5 call_function + 737
80  org.python.python               0x000000010342f32a _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 6742
81  org.python.python               0x00000001033a1e0c function_code_fastcall + 106
82  org.python.python               0x00000001034363d5 call_function + 737
83  org.python.python               0x000000010342f32a _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 6742
84  org.python.python               0x00000001033a1e0c function_code_fastcall + 106
85  org.python.python               0x00000001033a277f _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 131
86  org.python.python               0x00000001033dfac2 slot_tp_init + 80
87  org.python.python               0x00000001033dc7ee type_call + 172
88  org.python.python               0x00000001033a18ae _PyObject_FastCallKeywords + 358
89  org.python.python               0x00000001034363ce call_function + 730
90  org.python.python               0x000000010342f3de _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 6922
91  org.python.python               0x00000001033a1e0c function_code_fastcall + 106
92  org.python.python               0x00000001034363d5 call_function + 737
93  org.python.python               0x000000010342f343 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 6767
94  org.python.python               0x00000001033a1e0c function_code_fastcall + 106
95  org.python.python               0x00000001034363d5 call_function + 737
96  org.python.python               0x000000010342f32a _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 6742
97  org.python.python               0x00000001033a1e0c function_code_fastcall + 106
98  org.python.python               0x00000001034363d5 call_function + 737
99  org.python.python               0x000000010342f32a _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 6742
100 org.python.python               0x0000000103436bc9 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1698
101 org.python.python               0x00000001033a1678 _PyFunction_FastCallDict + 444
102 org.python.python               0x00000001033a277f _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 131
103 org.python.python               0x00000001033dfac2 slot_tp_init + 80
104 org.python.python               0x00000001033dc7ee type_call + 172
105 org.python.python               0x00000001033a18ae _PyObject_FastCallKeywords + 358
106 org.python.python               0x00000001034363ce call_function + 730
107 org.python.python               0x000000010342f486 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 7090
108 org.python.python               0x0000000103436bc9 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1698
109 org.python.python               0x00000001033a1a00 _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords + 212
110 org.python.python               0x00000001034363d5 call_function + 737
111 org.python.python               0x000000010342f486 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 7090
112 org.python.python               0x0000000103436bc9 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1698
113 org.python.python               0x00000001033a1678 _PyFunction_FastCallDict + 444
114 org.python.python               0x00000001033a277f _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 131
115 org.python.python               0x00000001033a1b45 PyObject_Call + 136
116 org.python.python               0x000000010342f627 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 7507
117 org.python.python               0x0000000103436bc9 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1698
118 org.python.python               0x00000001033a1678 _PyFunction_FastCallDict + 444
119 org.python.python               0x00000001033a277f _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 131
120 org.python.python               0x00000001033df0ce slot_tp_call + 71
121 org.python.python               0x00000001033a18ae _PyObject_FastCallKeywords + 358
122 org.python.python               0x00000001034363ce call_function + 730
123 org.python.python               0x000000010342f3de _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 6922
124 org.python.python               0x00000001033a1e0c function_code_fastcall + 106
125 org.python.python               0x00000001034363d5 call_function + 737
126 org.python.python               0x000000010342f32a _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 6742
127 org.python.python               0x0000000103436bc9 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1698
128 org.python.python               0x00000001033a1a00 _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords + 212
129 org.python.python               0x00000001034363d5 call_function + 737
130 org.python.python               0x000000010342f32a _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 6742
131 org.python.python               0x0000000103436bc9 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1698
132 org.python.python               0x00000001033a1a00 _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords + 212
133 org.python.python               0x00000001034363d5 call_function + 737
134 org.python.python               0x000000010342f32a _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 6742
135 org.python.python               0x0000000103436bc9 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1698
136 org.python.python               0x00000001033a1678 _PyFunction_FastCallDict + 444
137 org.python.python               0x00000001033a277f _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 131
138 org.python.python               0x00000001033a1b45 PyObject_Call + 136
139 org.python.python               0x000000010342f627 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 7507
140 org.python.python               0x0000000103436bc9 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1698
141 org.python.python               0x00000001033a1678 _PyFunction_FastCallDict + 444
142 org.python.python               0x00000001033a277f _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 131
143 org.python.python               0x00000001033a1b45 PyObject_Call + 136
144 org.python.python               0x000000010342f627 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 7507
145 org.python.python               0x00000001033a1e0c function_code_fastcall + 106
146 org.python.python               0x00000001034363d5 call_function + 737
147 org.python.python               0x000000010342f343 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 6767
148 org.python.python               0x0000000103436bc9 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1698
149 org.python.python               0x00000001033a1a00 _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords + 212
150 org.python.python               0x00000001034363d5 call_function + 737
151 org.python.python               0x000000010342f32a _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 6742
152 org.python.python               0x00000001033a1e0c function_code_fastcall + 106
153 org.python.python               0x00000001034363d5 call_function + 737
154 org.python.python               0x000000010342f32a _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 6742
155 org.python.python               0x0000000103436bc9 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1698
156 org.python.python               0x00000001033a1a00 _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords + 212
157 org.python.python               0x00000001034363d5 call_function + 737
158 org.python.python               0x000000010342f3de _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 6922
159 org.python.python               0x0000000103436bc9 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1698
160 org.python.python               0x000000010342d831 PyEval_EvalCode + 51
161 org.python.python               0x000000010345bc3c run_mod + 54
162 org.python.python               0x000000010345ac6f PyRun_FileExFlags + 160
163 org.python.python               0x000000010345a326 PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 270
164 org.python.python               0x0000000103472b2e pymain_main + 5445
165 org.python.python               0x000000010347319c _Py_UnixMain + 56
166 libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff6ec827fd start + 1

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x000000011554bab8  rbx: 0x0000000000000000  rcx: 0x00000001072cee6c  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x00007ff2617da290  rsi: 0x0000000000000001  rbp: 0x00007ffeec87a340  rsp: 0x00007ffeec879f00
   r8: 0x2bf4e2fa4089247b   r9: 0x00000000a5baadb8  r10: 0x00000000a5baadb9  r11: 0x000000001c2a1c07
  r12: 0x000000011554babc  r13: 0x0000000000000024  r14: 0x0000000000000002  r15: 0x00007ff2617da290
  rip: 0x00007fff6ee9fc45  rfl: 0x0000000000010206  cr2: 0x000000011554baba
 ...
```